# kinect toolbox c# syntax

Tags: c#, kinect, toolbox

I have been studying the algorithm used in kinect toolbox to compare vector sequences, but I am struggling to understand this piece of code:

```
 public static float DistanceTo(this List<Vector2> path1, List<Vector2> path2)
    {
        return path1.Select((t, i) => (t - path2[i]).Length).Average();
    }
```

as far as I understand this takes two sequences of 2d vectors and computes the distance between them by means of euclidean distance, that is, it calculates the length of the difference between vectors, I however had never seen the syntax inside the parenthesis, specially the =>.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply unroll this select statement.

`path1.Select((t, i) => (t - path2[i]).Length)` iterates over `path1`, for every element in it, it selects the `Vector2` element and its index in the `path1` list.

From that intermediate result it will do the difference between the two corresponding vectors at the same index (`t - path2[i]`), where `-` is a parameter overload for the vector substraction method. From that difference it will calculate the `vector length` which is basically just a squared(?) summation over its elements.

`Average()` in the end just takes the average over all the given vector differences.

This C# code is semantically the same:

```
float sum = 0.0f;
for(int i = 0; i < path1.Count; i++)
{
   sum += (path1[i] - path[2]).Length;
}
return sum / (float)path1.Count;
```

Or even nicer as a LINQ zip expression:

```
path1.Zip(path2, (left, right) => (left-right).Length).Average();
```